# WPF: MaxHeight to screen height

Tags: wpf, height, screen

how can I set the MaxHeight Property of a Window to screen height?

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="RT.MainWindow" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="{Binding WindowTitle}" Height="300" MaxHeight="500" Width="495.149" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
```

Comment: what do you mean by screen? Is it your monitor? If you dont define any MaxHeight then it means there is no MaxHeight right?

Comment: @Krishna yes I mean my monitor. If I dont define MaxHeight the window grows over the screen size (height)

Answer (score 12):

In the codebehind page of your control you can set the `MaxHeight` of your Window to

```
System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight
```

or you can use `SystemParameters.VirtualScreenHeight`